# How would I show custom text AND calculations in a list box?

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

(Picture is attached for reference)
I need to have "Year x:" followed by the calculation in a list box. I can get the calculations (incorrectly so far), but I'm not sure how to add the "Year x" part before each calculation.

[image: Reference]

Any help is appreciated. TIA!

Here is my code for the button click event:

private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
try
{

```
            if (DataIsValid())
            {
                // Change to Parse methods that check for formatting characters
                decimal monthlyInvestment =
                    Decimal.Parse(txtMonthlyInvestment.Text, NumberStyles.Currency);
                decimal interestRateYearly =
                    Decimal.Parse(txtInterestRate.Text, NumberStyles.Number);
                int years =
                    Int32.Parse(comboNumberOfYears.Text, NumberStyles.Number);

                int months = years * 12;
                decimal interestRateMonthly = interestRateYearly / 12 / 100;
                decimal futureValue = CalculateFutureValue(
                    monthlyInvestment, interestRateMonthly, months);

                // Add statements that format the values that are displayed
                // Monthly investment
                txtMonthlyInvestment.Text = monthlyInvestment.ToString("c");
                // Yearly interest rate
                txtInterestRate.Text = (interestRateYearly / 100).ToString("p2");
                // Future value
                listFutureValue.Items.Clear();
                for (int i = 1; i <= years; i++)
                {
                    futureValue /= i;
                    listFutureValue.Items.Add(futureValue.ToString("c"));
                }
                txtMonthlyInvestment.Focus();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This site provides a preview of your question for a reason. Please don't hit the submit button if your question is a mess. If you don't know how to format a question properly, visit the Help Center and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various options but they are all variations of the same thing. You just need to create a string that contains the literal part and the rest. The obvious option should have been this:

```cs
listFutureValue.Items.Add("Year " + i + ": " + futureValue.ToString("c"));
```

I'm not sure how you could not know that that was possible. That said, the better option would be this:

```cs
listFutureValue.Items.Add($"Year {i}: {futureValue:c}");
```

That's using string interpolation, which is basically direct language support for the `String.Format` method. You should read the documentation for that method and string interpolation for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying that, but kept getting an error. The second option worked without any errors for me, though

Comment: @Casey, for future reference, you're supposed to post what you tried and what the error(s) was in the question.